# Postgres CLI error: database "dev" does not exist on trying to run any psql command

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql, apple-m1

I install postgres version 14 using homebrew.

```
brew install postgresql
```

Whenever, I try to run psql command, I get the following error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: 
FATAL: database "dev" does not exist
```

Following are my system paths

```
/Users/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v15.14.0/bin:
/opt/homebrew/bin:
/opt/homebrew/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:
/Library/Apple/usr/bin:
```

Comment: You must be using the 'dev' name in your connection string? Can you show us that? The default db in postgres is called postgres there is no dev database.

Comment: Which psql command did you run?

Comment: @VynlJunkie sorry, i am new to Postgres and didn't know about that. 
You can set it in answer, and i'll mark it a solution.

It works if i explicitly specify database "postgres"
 psql -d postgres

Comment: I'm guessing the OS user you are running the `psql` command as is `dev`. If you do something in the terminal like  `psql` then the database user name will be the same as the OS user name and this will in turn make the database name the user name. It is best to be explicit: `psql -d <db_name> -U <db_user>` Spend some time here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be using the 'dev' name in your connection string? Can you show us that? The default db in postgres is called postgres there is no dev database.

When connecting to a fresh install of Postgres  entering `psql` into the command line actually executes something like

```
psql -d postgres -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost
```

Those are the default values so `psql` is fine.

You/your application is entering something like:

```
psql -d dev -U [user] -p [port] -h [host]
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@VynlJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432541/vynljunkie) said, your issue is connected with absence of `dev` database. There is one more thing you can do. Maybe you want to enter `psql` just like this:

```sh
> psql
```

You can do it by creating empty database named `dev`. So you enter `psql` the way [@VynlJunkie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4432541/vynljunkie) explained and run such query:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE dev;
```

Then you could access `psql` just using one term in terminal.

Comment: Be sure its the dev db you want to connect to in this instance, creating a db to account for a failing connection string seems counter intuitive.

Comment: For me it's a good UX. I use `psql` to enter `psql`, then I type `\c <first-letter-of-DB>` and `Tab`. For me it's faster. And if I use `psql` instead of IDE client I often want make queries to several databases.